# Jira Rest API Project creation with screen attached

Tags: jira, project, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create project on jira via rest api. I want to attach the setting of existing project to new project like we do while creating from jira dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This method is not documented in official documentation.

To Create Project hit the following URL as it is (10245 is the Project Id whose complete settings are going to be copied to new project) along with following payload

```
 https://*.atlassian.net/rest/project-templates/1.0/createshared/10245
{
"name": "Test Name", – bind with Project Name text box
"key": "TPSTS"  – bind with Project Key text box
"description": "Test description", – bind with Project Description text box
"url": "https://www.vfairs.com/", – bind with Event URL text box
"avatarId": 10497,
}
```